# xml file loading showing json error

Tags: xml, angular, http-headers, angular5, angular-httpclient

in my app i am trying to load `XML` file in order to use his data.
but i am facing an error in Chrome browser console:

> {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp…,

### service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ReadDataService {
  headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
  xml: string;
  private _url: string = "../../assets/sf9_commandpacket.xml";

 constructor(private _http:HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<string> {
  return this._http.get<string>(this._url, { headers: this.headers });
  }
 }
}
```

i see in the error, that he is trying to load `json`, why?

---

I tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315170/1310853):

```
this._http.get(this._url, { headers: this.headers, responseType: text / xml }).subscribe(response => { return response; })
```

but this appear:
[image: this appear]

also tried to surrong with `'`:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36370061/5695162

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276250/angular-4-httpclient-xml-response

Comment: Content-type is a way to specify the media type of request being sent from the client to the server ,and `HttpClient.get()` by default returns JSON if you are requesting non-JSON data you need to use  `responseType:'text'` option as mentioned in one of the link I have shared

Comment: @Vikas, i already stumbled across those, but they didn't work for me.
please see the question, i added in the bottom of the question

Comment: `this._http.get(this._url, {  responseType: ' text' }).subscribe(response => { console.log(response); });` Give this a try and temme what you see

Comment: i see the same thing that happen in the second image that i have attached

Comment: don't include header in the request